# Not Validating API according to the database

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, validation

This is the angular code for login validation. Everything is perfect in spring boot. But in the login form if I give the Id and password from the database. It says login successful. Even if I give wrong Id and password, it says login successful. It is not validating. Please let me know what is wrong here?!

**1) auth.service.ts**

```
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  
  USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'authenticatedUser'

  public patId!: number;
  public password!: String;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  authenticationService(patId :number, password: String) {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:8080/patientlogins`,
      { headers: { authorization: this.createBasicAuthToken(patId, password) } }).pipe(map((res) => {
        this.patId = patId;
        this.password = password;
        
      }));
  }

  createBasicAuthToken(patId: number, password: String) {
    return 'Basic ' + window.btoa(patId + ":" + password)
  }

  
  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    if (user === null) return false
    return true
  }

  getLoggedInpatId() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem(this.USER_NAME_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    if (user === null) return ''
    return user
  }
}
```

**2)login.component.html**

```
<div class="container col-lg-6">
    <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form class="form-group">
          <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf='invalidLogin'>{{errorMessage}}</div>
          <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf='loginSuccess'>{{successMessage}}</div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="number">PatientId:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patId" [(ngModel)]="patId" placeholder="Enter patId"
              name="patId">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password"
              name="password">
          </div>
          <button (click)=handleLogin() class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
          <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**3)login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AuthenticationService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  patId!: number;
  password!: string;
  errorMessage = 'Invalid Credentials';
  successMessage!: string;
  invalidLogin = false;
  loginSuccess = false;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  handleLogin() {
    this.authenticationService.authenticationService(this.patId, this.password).subscribe((result)=> {
      this.invalidLogin = false;
      this.loginSuccess = true;
      this.successMessage = 'Login Successful.';
      this.errorMessage='Invalid Login';
      
    }, () => {
      this.invalidLogin = true;
      this.loginSuccess = false;
    });      
  }
}
```

**4)app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**5)app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   
    LoginComponent,
        HomeComponent
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
() => {
        this.invalidLogin = true;
        this.loginSuccess = false;
      }
```

This part in `handleLogin` is executed only if http server returns error (500 or 503 or so on).

In your case, this will fix your problem.

```
  handleLogin() {
    this.authenticationService.authenticationService(this.patId, this.password).subscribe((result)=> {
      
      for (const obj of result) {
        if (obj.patId === this.patId && obj.password === this.password) {
          this.invalidLogin = false;
          this.loginSuccess = true;
          this.successMessage = 'Login Successful.';
          return;
        }
      }
      this.invalidLogin = true;
      this.loginSuccess = false;
      this.errorMessage='Invalid Login';
      
    }, () => {
      this.invalidLogin = true;
      this.loginSuccess = false;
    });      
  }
```

But I strongly suggest you not to return user password in http response. This will reveal user passwords to other users. You should check whether id and password matches in server side and just response the result.

Comment: so what exactly should I change in the code?

Comment: Please share the response of `http://localhost:8080/patientlogins`. Both of successful case and failure case.

Comment: As you told if I go to inspect and response I'm getting the data which is displayed in the database. Whenever I click on login the data is getting displayed in response.

Comment: If I go to http://localhost:8080/patientlogins .....[{"patId":863,"password":"*******"},{"patId":544,"password":"ededede"},{"patId":333,"password":"NDJEN"},{"patId":433,"password":"ededede"},{"patId":2,"password":"wswswws"},{"patId":3444,"password":"ededdeded"}].............I'm getting it displayed

Comment: I executed the code you have sent. When I give wrong password/patid and click on login it shows nothing.

Comment: even if i give wrong password I'm getting the data displayed in response

Comment: It is your server issue. Outside scope of this question. I suggest you to post a new question with your server code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70121819/not-able-validate-id-and-password-through-angular

Comment: I have read your new question. I looks the API `patientlogins` just returns all users without authentication and other methods also do not do any authentication. Unfortunately I am not famillier with spring, I can not provide you a helpful solution.